# How to get mp3 files path inside folder and its subfolders in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a function to check `.mp3` files inside any folder. I know little about regexp. Following is my code what I tried still receiving empty array.

```js
const find = require('find') ;
const path = require('path') ;
const mm = require('music-metadata') ;

async function parseMetadata(files){
   let metadata ;
   data = files.map(async (file) => {
      metadata = await mm.parseFile(file,{duration:true}) ;
      m = new metaData(metadata.common, metadata.format.duration, file) ;
      return m ;
   }) ;

   const musicarray = await Promise.all(data) ;
   return musicarray ;
}


function fetchmp3(dirs){
   let res,musicfiles = [] ;
   dirs.forEach((path)=>{
      res = find.fileSync(/\.(mp3)/ig,path) ;
      musicfiles.push(...res) ;
   });

   if (musicfiles.length === 0){
      return parseMetadata(musicfiles) ;
   }
   else{
      return Promise.resolve([]) ;
   }
}
```

So, I want that the function `fetchmp3` to recieve all data related to mp3 files inside given folder and it's subfolders. Currently my code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried @RasoulSalehi regexp still it returned `[]`. I used debugger checked the value of `musicfiles` it was having 40 entries so I checked again my function and realized that in if condition  it must be `musicfiles.length !== 0` not `musicfiles.length === 0`. Literally, wasted 1-2 days for the problem searched whole internet for cause of problem and I thought that my older regexp mas incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your regular expression not working correctly, you can use this

```
[\w]+\.(mp3)
```

Also, "\w" matches the name with word Character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) if you have any special characters other than "_" in your file name you can add it after "\w" to match them to.
For example, if you have "." in your file name like "something.some.mp3" you can add it like this

```
[\w.]+\.(mp3)
```

You regular expression matching just ".mp3".